# What happened to the paint on my 2014 Toyota Prius V? Is there a way I can DIY repair it?

Tags: paint, diy, paint-scratches

Backed into a pole at very low speed, compressed bumper slightly, which caused this tearing in the paint job of a black Toyota 2014 Prius V.

I didn't even know that this was possible, but I want to try to DIY it.
I'm afraid that if I try to peel the flakey parts, that it will continue to peel more of the paint off.

What is the best way for me to DIY a repair here? Is there a name for this phenomenon that I can search Youtube for?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 7):

It looks like typical Toyota paint to me. The paint is delaminating from the soft bumper. You can paint this yourself, but you'd need a paint gun, compressor, special tools, and some understanding of how to apply it. I couldn't tell you exactly how to do it, just saying it is doable. Still going to cost you money. If the bumper is the only thing where this is happening, your best bet is to pull the bumper and take it somewhere to be finished. Pulling the bumper isn't very hard. There's plenty of videos online of how to pull it off. Taking it somewhere to get done is going to be far cheaper than buying the equipment needed to do it yourself.

Comment: Eh, depending on the quality of bumper paint you want, this can be done pretty cheaply with some spray cans.

Comment: @Davor - You can always paint it, but it is doubtful you're going to get any type of quality out of a spray can. Bumpers require special paint additives so the primer/paint remains flexible. If it is not included, it'll peel off again in short order.